# D3.js fill part of graph with background

Tags: d3.js, background, linechart

I have a basic line chart with two lines like this

[image: line chart]

I want to apply background in part where only blue line is to highlight part where both lines are. What is the best way to do this in D3.js?

Part of my code

```
x = d3.time.scale()
  .domain([date_from, date_to])
  .range([0, width])

y = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([15, 30])
  .range([height, 0])

line = d3.svg.line()
  .x((d, i) -> x(parseDate(d.date)))
  .y((d) -> y(d.price))

svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg:svg")
  .attr("width", width + 50)
  .attr("height", height + 50)
  .append("svg:g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(25, 25)")

svg.append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0, #{height})")
  .call(xAxis)

svg.append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "grid")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0, #{height})")
  .call(xAxis.tickSize(-height, 0, 0).tickFormat("").ticks(80))

svg.append("svg:g")
  .attr("class", "grid")
  .call(yAxis.tickSize(-width, 0, 0).tickFormat("").ticks(40))

svg.append("svg:path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", line(data))
  .style("stroke", (d) -> color("year"))

svg.append("svg:path")
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", line(data2))
  .style("stroke", (d) -> color("month"))
```

Comment: Can you post your code for creating this example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Draw a `rect` element on that portion of the chart.

```
var rectangle = svg.append("rect")
                    .attr("x", 0)
                    .attr("y", 0)
                    .attr("width", x(firstXValueOfSecondLine))
                    .attr("height", chartHeight)
                    .style('opacity', 0.5)
                    .style('fill', '#ededed');
```